# Learning about Proofs and how to write them? (A programmer's perspective)

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, proof-writing, computer-science, cryptography

I have a B.S. Degree in computer science and have taken more math classes then the average person but not enough to consider myself good at it. I have been briefly introduced to proofs.

I'm currently writing a very simple algorithm and its corresponding program which builds upon the heavily used [Secure Hash Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm). I'm willing to conceded that the complexity in that set of algorithms is beyond my understanding and will assume they do what they say (Two different inputs will rarely [*Astronomically high chance of it happening*] create the same outputs and the same inputs will always create the same outputs). I would like to prove or disprove that my small algorithm does not break this.

**I need to (re)learn about proofs and how to write them and how to go from my algorithm pseudo code to a proof showing that it doesn't break SHA's properties, Where do I start?**

**What I know about the algorithm and the mathematics involved:** The algorithm uses a SHA hash to transverse a circular list of 1000 words. The Numbers and Letters in the SHA hash determines in which direction and how many spaces to move. This is used to build a list of 20 words. Is this list of 20 words just as collision resistant (Hard for 2 different hashes to create the same word list) as the original SHA hash.

I guess the first thing I would need to know is the chances of a collision using the SHA algorithms.

And then...

A Combinatorics proof which is where my problems start.

1000 words in a circular list.

2 directions (left and right)

Hashes of arbitrary length.

Comment: Your problem is one of combinatorics, I see (hashing). However, you have not stated what are you trying to prove: the algorithms complexity or the fact that two inputs rarely give the same output (or something else)?

Comment: @theSongbird not complexity as the algorithm is just operations on a list and so I'm not to worried about that. I'm leaning more towards your second guess but it could be the something else you mentioned.

Comment: OK, so basically you'd like to give a formal proof as to why SHA has a very low chance to get the same result from different inputs.

Comment: @theSongbird no I'm assuming SHA is correct, I'd like to give a formal proof of my algorithm (which uses the SHA output) and prove that the chance of collision (same output for different inputs) is as equally astronomical.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of your algorithm (don't try to hold back, I'm also a CS student)

Comment: @theSongbird I've added a simple description of the algorithm in the original posted question.